# How to display PhotosPicker via swiftUI Image LongPressGesture?

Tags: swift, swiftui, photosui

I would like to display a `PhotosUI` `PhotosPicker` via a `longPressGesture` of a `UIImage`.

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

@MainActor
final class TestViewModelProfile: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var selectedImage: UIImage? = nil
    @Published var imageSelection: PhotosPickerItem? = nil {
        didSet {
            setImage(from: imageSelection)
        }
    }
    
    private func setImage(from selection: PhotosPickerItem?) {
        guard let selection else { return }
        
        Task {
            if let data = try? await selection.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                if let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                    selectedImage = uiImage
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}


struct ProfilePageViewTest: View {
    
    
    @State var profilePhoto: Image?
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = PhotoPickerViewModel()
    

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            if let image = viewModel.selectedImage {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .gesture(
                        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1.0)
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                // Perform image upload logic here
                                uploadProfilePhoto()
                            }
                    )
                
            } else {
                Image("No Profile Picture")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .gesture(
                        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1.0)
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                // Perform image upload logic here
                                uploadProfilePhoto()
                            }
                    )
                
                
                //PhotosPicker can be presented like this, but just via selection of the text as its own link
                PhotosPicker(selection: $viewModel.imageSelection, matching: .images) {
                    
                    Text("Open the photoPicker")
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    
        
    }
    
    func uploadProfilePhoto() {
        //present the PhotosPicker
    }
}


    



struct ProfilePageViewTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfilePageViewTest().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

In the example code I have both the unsatisfactory current approach, where the PhotosPicker can be opened via selection of the "Open the photoPicker" text below the image, and a placeholder for a function which I would like to have open the photopicker via long press.

The issue is I do not how to simply present the PhotoPicker as a result of a function, rather than manually creating, effectively, a button via the body of `PhotosPicker(...){ <body> }`.

The end goal is actually to have `uploadProfilePhoto` *first* display a `VStack` of a few buttons: "Change profile photo", "View", "Cancel" and have the first one actually display the PhotosPicker, but if I can understand how to simply display the PhotosPicker as result of function, I can incorporate it into this overlayed button view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a different approach to achieve your end goal,
of `...first display a VStack of a few buttons: "Change profile photo", "View", "Cancel" and have the first one actually display the PhotosPicker`

Using a `.sheet` and a `PhotosPicker` as a Button, as shown in the example code

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ProfilePageViewTest()
    }
}

@MainActor
final class PhotoPickerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var selectedImage: UIImage? = nil
    @Published var imageSelection: PhotosPickerItem? = nil {
        didSet {
            setImage(from: imageSelection)
        }
    }
    
    private func setImage(from selection: PhotosPickerItem?) {
        guard let selection else { return }
        
        Task {
            if let data = try? await selection.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                if let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                    selectedImage = uiImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct ProfilePageViewTest: View {
    @State var profilePhoto: Image?
    @StateObject private var viewModel = PhotoPickerViewModel()
    @State var showSelector = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let image = viewModel.selectedImage {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "photo") // for testing
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
        }
        .onLongPressGesture {
            showSelector = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSelector) {
            VStack (spacing: 55){
                PhotosPicker(selection: $viewModel.imageSelection, matching: .images) {
                    Text("Change profile photo")
                }
                Button("View") {
                    // ...
                }
                Button("Cancel") {
                    // ...
                    showSelector = false
                }
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
            .onChange(of: viewModel.imageSelection) { //<-- here
                showSelector = false
            }
            // .onChange(of: viewModel.imageSelection) { _ in  // <-- here
            //    showSelector = false
            //  }
        }
    }
    
}
```

EDIT-1

You can of course use a simple `if`, such as:

```
struct ProfilePageViewTest: View {
    @State var profilePhoto: Image?
    @StateObject private var viewModel = PhotoPickerViewModel()
    @State var showSelector = false 
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let image = viewModel.selectedImage {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "photo") // for testing
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
            Spacer()
            if showSelector {  // <--- here
                VStack (spacing: 55){
                    PhotosPicker(selection: $viewModel.imageSelection, matching: .images) {
                        Text("Change profile photo")
                    }
                    Button("View") {
                        // ...
                        showSelector = false
                    }
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        // ...
                        showSelector = false
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 30)
        .onLongPressGesture{
            showSelector = true
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-2:

using a simple tap on the picture, to choose/change the profile photo.

```
struct ProfilePageViewTest: View {
    @State var profilePhoto: Image?
    @StateObject private var viewModel = PhotoPickerViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PhotosPicker(selection: $viewModel.imageSelection, matching: .images) {
                if let image = viewModel.selectedImage {
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why I would use one approach over the other? I have seen the first used more in often in docs, despite the second being simpler. Why is it usually the former?

Comment: It is often a sheet that is used, because the Apple Human Interface Guidelines for 
[Sheet](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sheets) describes it as a useful approach for "... for requesting specific information from people or presenting a simple task that they can complete before returning to the parent view.".  
It is really up to you as to which approach you use, considering **your** overall look and feel of **your App**.
If it was me, I would use a simple tap on the picture to change it, not a onLongPressGesture. See `EDIT-2`

Comment: Understood. When I go with the first answer, selecting the photo correctly updates the image on the ProfileViewPageTest view, but you need to manually close the sheet that opens from the long press (the PhotosPicker closes, but not the sheet containing the 3 options). I tried to throw a `showSelector.toggle()` within the `setImage()` func but it is out of scope. How can I close this sheet immediately after photo update s/t the user doesn't need to close it after the image is selected from the PhotosPicker?

Comment: to `...close this sheet immediately after photo update s/t the user doesn't need to close it after the image is selected from the PhotosPicker` use a `.onChange(...)`,
 as shown in my updated answer (in the sheet).
 Note that you would be better off using the more conventional and intuitive UI
 of clicking/tapping on the photo to bring up just the `PhotosPicker`,
 not the `.sheet` with the duplicate `Cancel` and the strange `View` buttons.

Comment: .onChange is only available in IOS 17.0 or newer and thus throws an error. I can wrap the view in @Available but what is method to do this in earlier versions too? Further, what do you mean duplicate `Cancel`? 

And I do not want to do it on tap. Clicking the photo should bring a zoomed-in view of it, not immediately prompt change.

Comment: It seems that `.onChange(...)` was introduced in ios-14, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)
 
 If you are targeting ios-14 or up to ios-17,
you can use the older `.onChange(...)` with one parameter, as shown in the updated code.
 If you are targeting ios-13 or lower, you may need to use the Combine framework,
 somehow, eg `.onReceive(...)`.
 
 What I mean by duplicate `Cancel`, is that the `PhotosPicker` itself has a `Cancel` option
 when it pops up.

Comment: Note that, `PhotosPicker` itself requires ios-16+.
 If you are targeting ios-16, then use the older (now deprecated) version
 of `.onChange(...) { _ in ...}` with one closure parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.photosPicker(isPresented: $isShowingPicker, selection: $viewModel.imageSelection)
```

Instead of

```
 PhotosPicker(selection: $viewModel.imageSelection, matching: .images)
```

Here is a full set of code.

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

@MainActor
final class TestViewModelProfile: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var selectedImage: UIImage? = nil
    @Published var imageSelection: PhotosPickerItem? = nil
    
    func setImage() async throws {
        guard let imageSelection else { return }
        
        guard let data = try await imageSelection.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) 
        else {throw LocalError.missingImageData}
        
        guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) 
        else { throw LocalError.unableToCreateImage }
        
        selectedImage = uiImage
    }
    private enum LocalError: LocalizedError {
        case missingImageData
        case unableToCreateImage
    }
}


struct ProfilePageViewTest: View {
    @State private var profilePhoto: Image?
    @StateObject private var viewModel = TestViewModelProfile()
    @State private var isShowingPicker: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let image = viewModel.selectedImage {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .gesture(
                        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1.0)
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                // Perform image upload logic here
                                uploadProfilePhoto()
                            }
                    )
                
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .gesture(
                        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1.0)
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                // Perform image upload logic here
                                uploadProfilePhoto()
                            }
                    )
            }
        }.photosPicker(isPresented: $isShowingPicker, selection: $viewModel.imageSelection)
            .task(id: viewModel.imageSelection) {
                do {
                    try await viewModel.setImage()
                } catch {
                    print (error) //Show error to user.
                }
            }
    }
    
    func uploadProfilePhoto() {
        isShowingPicker.toggle()
    }
}


#Preview {
    ProfilePageViewTest()
}
```